Restore Dual Boot
I was running Windows 10/Ubuntu Dual boot system.
I had some problem with grub and somehow fixed it and continued with only Ubuntu.
I want to restore the dual boot option.
I don't remember exactly what I did to move to only ubuntu. I used boot-repair I think.
Now I am checking the directories under /boot/efi/EFI.
There are 3 directories there.
Boot, Microsoft_bak, ubuntu
This is boot summary from boot-repair tool.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rkWN4PzpBX/
Can you please help me restore to windows/ubuntu dual boot?
Update:
New boot summary:
https://text.is/PZZY4

Can you repost the boot summary to a site that doesn't require an account? Also curious about the Microsoft_bak directory: did you do that, or was it the repair tool?

Can you directly boot Windows from system's UEFI boot menu? If not then a Windows issue.  Grub only boots working Windows. And that includes fast startup must be off and no chkdsk required. Do not try BIOS boot as you have gpt drives which for Windows can only boot in UEFI boot mode. The Windows boot loaders in MBR, should not really even be there, but as long as you never try BIOS boot (which will fail) having Windows BIOS boot loader in MBR will not cause other issues.

@ajgringo619 By the name of it, I must have created that directory. Also, added a new link for boot info summary.

@oldfred No, I can't boot directly to windows.

If you cannot boot Windows from UEFI, then it is a Windows issue. I also have never seen a Microsoft.bak folder in ESP. I might back up ESP and try renaming those to Microsoft. If you look at line 110 the UEFI entry is trying to boot the standard Windows entry of /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.

You can't boot directly into Windows because the EFI entry is looking for \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI, which doesn't exist. Try renaming Microsoft_bak to Microsoft, then run sudo update-grub.
